# Is it ok to share Coding Game puzzle solution for golf improvement?

Tags: discussion, spoilers

I want to share my golfed code of puzzle available on [Coding Game](https://www.codingame.com), but is it OK to share it on CodeGolf SE ? Other's code is available only by completing the puzzle, but I use those puzzle to train code-golf.

Is sharing my solution and/or asking for possible improvement OK ?
Should I use a

> spoiler ?

[Here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/197243/88473) an example and [here](https://www.codingame.com/ide/puzzle/ascii-art) the puzzle my question is about.

Comment: Is this a question about our policy or about the other site's policy?  You are certainly allowed to show your code and ask for help golfing it here as [tag:tips], like the question you linked, however I don't I don't know the rules for the other site (whether it is ok to get help writing your code) and this is not really the place to ask about that site.

Comment: I ask for SE policy. I asked on CG but no answer yet. Will update is so.

Comment: For practice exercice, no issue in sharing the solution for CG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) is for.

You can share your code and what it is trying to do and others can show you how it can be improved.  You can put your code in a spoiler block if you would like but it is definitely not necessary to do so.

It may of course be against another sites terms to submit code you have received help on, even if that help was golfing it, so you may want to check their policy.

Comment: Ok, my goal is to improve my knowledge, not improve my score on this website, so I will not publish the improved version on it. I asked to a community chat of CG, and the answer is that in my case, it's ok. For challenge and leader-board, probably not.